# Find all integers $n$ such that $n^2-7n+10$ is divisible by $n-3$.

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $n$ such that $n^2-7n+10$ is divisible by $n-3$.

I have been advised to find an expression containing $n^2$ that is divisible by $n-3$, but I don't see how that would help at the moment.

Comment: Hint: Set $n-3=h\iff n=h+3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have 
$$n^2 - 7n+10 = n^2 - 6n+9 -n+1 = (n-3)^2 -n+1 = (n-3)^2 - (n-3) -2.$$

Thus the expression is divisible by $n-3$ if and only if 
$-2$ is. Finding all these $n$ should not be that hard. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that $n^2-7n+10=(n-3)(n-4)-2$

Answer (score 2):

I did the  division and got $$n^2-7 n+10=n-4-\frac{2}{n-3}$$
and this shows that $n-3$ must be divisible by $\pm 2$, therefore

$1\le n\le 5\land n\ne 3$ which  gives only $n=1;\;n=2;\;n=4;\;n=5$.

Comment: The denominator on the LHS is missing.